# Can I use parted resize for partitions used by mdadm

Tags: parted

I have upgraded  3Tb drives in my RAID-5 to 5Tb one by one with same partitioning. I want to grow each of the partitions (at the end of the disc) to take the extra 2Tb.

I looked at `parted resize` but it is expecting a filesystem on the partition (and I don't think that is the filesystem on the RAID).

Each of the drives has 2 partitions, for example `/dev/sdd1` and `/dev/sdd2` (the raid partition).

How can I resize the raid partition on these drives? Can I do so while the system is running?

Ubuntu 14.04 Server

Comment: Also, `mdadm -E /dev/sdd1` to make sure you're not using version 0.9 or 1.0 superblocks. Resize is much harder with those...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you should not be using `resize` on an partition that is part of a RAID and no you should not do so while mounted.

You probably should not use the `parted` that you have **at all**. AFAIK Ubuntu 14.04 comes with the outdated parted 2.3 (check with `parted -v`) and the `resize` command has been removed in 3.0.

Download and compile the source for 3.2 from [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/parted/parted-3.2.tar.xz) (main parted page is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/)) and make sure you have `libdevmapper-dev` and `uuid-dev` installed:

```
apt-get install libdevmapper-dev uuid-dev libreadline-dev
```

(you might need some more these were the ones I had to install additionally to what I already had on my not so clean system, based on the feedback from `./configure`).

You should follow the instructions in the `INSTALL` file, which essentially are the usual `./configure && make && sudo make install`.

The 3.2 version of `parted` has a `resizepart` command that takes a partition number and the new end of the partition as parameters. *This works even on
  mounted partitions*

**Of course having a recent backup is a proper precaution if you do this.**